# IF statement definition for spinner in string arrays

Tags: android, arrays, if-statement, spinner

I want to define an if statement in my spinner resources which gets arrays from string array resources.

For example if I choose VQE in spinner_type spinner, I have to choose `call_VQ` in string resource. If I choose TFE in spinner-type spinner, I have to choose the `call_TF` array list in the resources.

The spinner code is:

```java
Spinner spinner_mode = findViewById(R.id.spinner_mode);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter_mode = new ArrayAdapter<String>(New.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.call_VQ));        myAdapter_mode.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_mode.setAdapter (myAdapter_mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set different variable for the adapter like below:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter_mode;

    if(VQE==true && TFE == false){
        myAdapter_mode = new ArrayAdapter<String>(New.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.call_VQ)); 
    } 
    if(VQE==false && TFE == true){
        myAdapter_mode = new ArrayAdapter<String>(New.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.call_VQ)); 
   }
```

In OnCreate set one value true and one value false by default. Then Change the true and false value by button onclick or whatever you wish.